# Unable to boot Ubuntu after power failure

Tags: boot, 13.10

The battery in my laptop became dislodged, and when I turned my laptop back on and tried to boot ubuntu I was faced with this:

```
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init=bootarg.

BusyBox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)
```

After reading in other forums that a potential fix was to boot Slax OS from a live USB, and from the terminal run:

```
e2fsck -y -f -v /dev/sda1
```

After about 3 and a half hours the process was complete, so I restarted my laptop and tried to boot Ubuntu once again.

I was now faced with a slightly different message:

```
mounting proc on /root/proc failed
```

I restarted my laptop and selected Recovery Mode from the grub menu. Booting into recovery eventually failed and this message was displayed:

```
mounting proc on /root/proc failed
friendly-recovery pre-start process (186) terminated with status 127
friendly-recovery post-start process (187) terminated with status 127.
```

I am now at a loss as to how to proceed. I can view the contents of the internal hdd through Slax if that makes a difference. I'm a bit of a linux-noob so be gentle!

Thanks

UPDATE: a list of commands run from the grub console and their outputs

```
command: ls
output: (hd0) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)

command: ls (hd0)
output: Device hd0: no known filesystem detected - Total size 1953525168 sectors

command: ls (hd0,1)
output: Partition hd0,1: Filesystem type ext* - Partition start at 2048 - Total size 1920980992 sectors ( I have a feeling that this is the Ubuntu partition)

command: ls (hd0,2)
output: Partition hd0,2: no known filesystem detected - Partition start at 1920983040 - Total size 32540672 sectors

command: ls (hd0,3)
output: error: no such partition
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is  grub has lost track of where Ubuntu is installed.

Press c to enterin grub console when grub appears.
First determine in which partition operating system is installed.You can determine it by checking the output of this.

STEP:1

```
ls (hdX,Y) //x is the drive number, and y the partition
```

Change the value of x(a,b,c ...etc) and y(0,1,2..etc.) appropriately. for example (hda,0),(hda,1) untill you are not getting your root partition.

once you get correct x and y, enter this

STEP:2

```
grub:>> set prefix=(hdX,Y)/boot/grub 
grub:>> set root=(hdX,Y)
grub:>> set
grub:>> ls /boot
grub:>> insmod /boot/grub/linux.mod
grub:>> linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sdXY ro  // x could be a or b or c, and y a number in my case was sda5 
grub:>> initrd /initrd.img 
grub:>> boot
```

now you get login into your ubuntu session.
After it type

STEP:3

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot.

Comment: Not sure where I'm going wrong: 
root@slax:~# 'ls (hda, 1)'
bash: ls (hda, 1): command not found
root@slax:~# ls (hda,1)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Only just seen what you said about doing it from the grub console. I'll try now and get back to you! Thanks for your help

Comment: ok. I have edited my post.

Comment: Just tried the ls command from grub console and get errors. if it helps, i know my ubuntu partition is installed at sda1

Comment: what error you are getting..

Comment: you can also try ls(hd0,1)

Comment: yeah I tried just 'ls' and got a list of the options available. how do i know which isn't the root partition?... also sorry for the delayed replies, I only have one laptop available to me so am having to boot back into slax each time I have a new question..

Comment: ls will list all the drives and partitions which grub can look at to find an OS. (hd0) is the first drive. (hd0,1) is the first partition on that drive. You need to type ls (hd0,1) (without quotes) at the grub prompt and see whether there are files called something like "vmlinuz" and "initrd" there. I don't know what your setup is, so you may have a lot of partitions to check until you find the one you need.

Comment: I have edited my original post to show the output of certain commands input into the grub console

Comment: have you given up helping me? @guru prasad

Comment: From your post, as I can see, your ubuntu partition is (hd0,1).So you got the correct value of X and Y that  is 0 and 1 respectively. Now put 0 in place of X and put 1 in place of Y in step 2.