# Unable to boot ubuntu after applying upgrades

Tags: upgrade

Yesterday, I was updating my laptop which was running 11.04 (I think from memory) and there was a battery problem, so then I kicked of the off again. All seemed OK and then when done, it showed Ubuntu 14.04.

However, when I rebooted I had the issue as shown in this post [same initial error message](https://askubuntu.com/questions/387178/unable-to-boot-ubuntu-after-power-failure)

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a flash pen and was able to run Boot Repair on it. This worked well, but now when I try to boot the updated system I now get the following:

***Serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /
Press I to ignore, S to skip mounting or M to manually recover***

I tried Skip and Ignore. This did not work. Then I tried M for manual recovery and this sent me to a screen where I could not do anything.

Can anyone please help as i would love to get my old profile back and running the new 14.04

Comment: Why not install afresh?

Comment: What exactly does *"so then I kicked of the off again"* mean? You turned off the computer without doing a safe shutdown? Clearly "*Serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for `/`*", so did you run the `fsck`/`e2fsck` like the question you linked had as it's first step?

Comment: Not too sure if I have explained this good, will try again:
 1. Performed upgrade, Battery failed (not shoutdown correctly), kicked off again (went all the way & brought up the 14.04 screen)
 2. Closed down Ubuntu then booted up & got message as per link I added
 3. Created a Live USB, booted from it & performed the boot repair
 4. Booted laptop & got the "Serious errors were found while checking the disk drive for /" message
 5. I can boot into 14.04 from a previous release (Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0.0-70-generic but not without selecting Advanced Options

Comment: Forgot to add that I didn't run the fsck/e2fsck as I thought that the Boot Repair tool had fixed this issue and I was getting new ones.

Comment: I tried the fsck / e2fcck while logged into under the usb stick and I got the following: e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
Warning!  /dev/sda1 is mounted.
e2fsck: Permission denied while trying to open /dev/sda1
You must have r/w access to the filesystem or be root

Comment: It is looking more like I will have to put a fresh version on, which will be a shame but not impossible.  it is a shame as I have not had much luck when upgrading the current version.

Comment: Just booted, got the message and pressed M to manually mount. Entered in as per the error message and got the following - /dev/sda1 is mounted. e2fsck: cannot continue, aborting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I have now fixed this issue after a long time going through the possible options on the Internet. I have just booted all OK into the latest version of Ubuntu on my machine, which I am happy about.

This is what i found [this worked for me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HIKf_uM9FHI) and worked a treat. I loved the video as I was able to follow it step by step. The first boot was slow. but I hope that this will improve after a few boots.